# WORDPRESS: Transition of post with nextnav and prenav but limit to 3

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my index.php, what i want to do is to display 3 Posts only to the page and put nextnav to show the next 3 post then prenav to get back to the previous 3 posts. Can anyone  show me how?

my code starts here:

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=10' );?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( have_posts():the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $link[0]; ?>" target="new _blank"><?php the_post_thumbnail(    "medium" ); ?></a>
<?php the_content(); ?>                                 
<?php endwhile; ?>                              
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel, you should try paging for this purpose.

```
 <?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
```

and pass the argument as per your requirement.

```
<?php $args = array(
'base'         => '%_%',
'format'       => '?page=%#%',
'total'        => 1,
'current'      => 0,
'show_all'     => False,
'end_size'     => 1,
'mid_size'     => 2,
'prev_next'    => True,
'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
'type'         => 'plain',
'add_args'     => False,
'add_fragment' => ''
 ); ?>
```

for more information refer this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links